# Precautions for inserting data to database using $_GET?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 1 main website, and I want to insert data in that my main website from an iPhone app. In this case, I was thinking of inserting data via $_GET, what are some precautions I should take if I do it this way? Any other solutions? Would this be called an API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you take precautions to prevent [SQL Injection Attacks, as described on the PHP documentation site](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

[Wikipedia has good summary of Code Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) in general.

Other types of injection you should be especially concerned about as a PHP developer would include (but are not necessarily limited to):

- "Shell Command Injection" - see [PHP's escapeshellarg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php).
- "include file injection" - Avoid including files whose names are generated directly from data that was submitted by the user.  If you must do this, then parse the value, and force the included file to be within a "safe" directory within your application, where no other sensitive data or non-idempotent script can be found.

There's a lot of reading available on the internet.  Take some time with google to track it down and read it.  These techniques and concerns apply to all languages and platforms--not just PHP--so you'll always use the information that you learn.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick summary... imagine if someone entered `"1'; DROP TABLE users; --"`. Your SQL query might look something like this: `"...WHERE id='1'; DROP TABLE users; --';"`. (`--` in SQL is a comment - everything after it is ignored.) Eventually they'll guess one of your table names correctly, and you've lost everything. Or they could do this put "Administrator" in the username field and `"password' OR 1=1; --"` in the password field, resulting in a query that looks like this `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='Administrator' AND password='pass' OR 1=1; --';"`. As 1=1 always evaluates to true, they'll be able to log in as anyone they want.

To avoid this, just do `$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['password'],$query_reference);` for all your `$_GET` vars.